# How to properly display characters in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, utf-8, fonts, terminal, icons

I am connecting to my ubuntu 16.04.2 server virtual machine through Putty.

When I open the [this](https://github.com/kracejic/dotfiles/blob/master/tmuxline) file in terminal, I get empty rectangles where icons should be.

Actual icons and as displayed in terminal:

[image] [image]

How do I display the icons in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PuTTY, there are two things to check (in PuTTY's settings dialog):

- ensure that the *Remote character set* (in the *Window/Translation* section) is set to UTF-8
- select a font which has the given characters (in *Window/Appearance*).  In a quick check, the default *Courier New* does **not**, while *Lucida Console* **does** — partly.

Once I made those changes, the file displayed properly for *some* of the special characters (CALENDAR and MUSIC).  The others did not.  They use these codes: U+25C0, U+231A and U+2388

If I used the *Consolas* font, that shows a backward question mark for those codes (a slight improvement).

If you don't mind using proportional fonts, *Tahoma* has the first of those codes.  *Lucida Sans Unicode* fares no better.

If you have Microsoft Office installed, it adds fonts which can help a lot.  I recall that its *Arial* has pretty good coverage.  But the bundled version of *Arial* which I see on the Windows machine at hand is not so good.

That still leaves the last two (CLOCK and CPUIMG).  You *might* find a suitable font, but offhand, the only ones with *good* coverage cost a little more.  Not free.  (A corollary to this is that most of the ones offered for some cost don't have good coverage).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually solved the issue right after I posted the question. The problem was that I was trying to install the correct fonts in Ubuntu without realizing that I needed the same fonts in windows for PuTTY to display characters correctly. Once I installed the fonts in both windows and ubuntu, everything worked.